Get a compile-time index to a std::variant when visiting it?
I have a std::variant of possibly repeated types, and I would like to increment the active index of the variant.
Here is an example demonstrating what I would like to do:
template <typename... Ts>
bool update_variant(std::variant<Ts>& v, std::tuple<work_generator<Ts>>& gen) {
    return visit_with_index([&]<size_t Index /* the active index */>(auto& e) {
        if (e.done()) {
            // we are done with e
            constexpr size_t next_index = Index + 1;
            if constexpr (next_index == sizeof...(Ts)) {
                // no more other work to do
                return false;
            } else {
                // still have other work to do so we move on to the next variant alternative
                v.emplace(
                        std::in_place_index_t<next_index>{},
                        std::get<next_index>(gen).create_worker()
                    );
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            // do some work on e, so e gets closer to the done state
            e.do_some_work();
            return true;
        }
    }, v);
}

To implement this, I seem to need something akin to visit_with_index above, which gives me the current index as a compile-time value.
Other than writing my own version of visit_with_index above, which is effectively writing my own version of std::visit, are there any simpler ways to achieve what I want without performing more than one lookup by index?

Can you not use std::variant::index to get the index of the current type in the variant?

That's not a compile-time constant, so I'd need to reimplement std::visit to turn it into a compile-time constant.

Why is compile-time so important? For a variant of N types, you'd end up with N-1 identical functions (only the last one is different), which seems like a waste.

@JaMiT: compile time is important for emplace(std::in_place_index_t<next_index>)

@Jarod42 It's also important for std::get<next_index>, but I don't think someone should have to dig through the code to figure that out.

It looks like there's a close duplicate. "increment" std::variant alternative differs in that it does not specify whether or not types can repeat (most of the answers work with repeated types) and in that it assumes default construction of the value. It does not look hard to add std::get<next_index>(gen).create_worker() into those answers, though, and in fact the answers here basically duplicate answers there. So I'll close this as a dupe, but I'll understand if there is some detail I missed that makes this question different.

I would use visit on the index "directly".
First
template <typename... Ts>
auto get_index_variant(const std::variant<Ts...>& v)
{
    return [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        using Ret = std::variant<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...>;
        std::array<Ret, sizeof...(Is)> a = {{Ret{std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}}...}};
        return a[v.index()];
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}

Then
std::visit([&](auto index){ // index() is constexpr
    // ...
    }, get_index_variant(v));

Demo

The double braces in std::array<Ret, sizeof...(Is)> a = {{Ret{std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}}...}}; should be single braces.

If all you care about it single visitation, then Boost.Mp11's mp_with_index is already what you want:
template <typename... Ts>
bool update_variant(std::variant<Ts...>& v, std::tuple<work_generator<Ts>>& gen) {
    return mp_with_index<sizeof...(Ts)>(v.index(), [&](auto I){
        // ... 
    });
}

Here I is an integral_constant<size_t, V> for some V, so it can be directly used like std::get<I>(x).
Internally, mp_with_index<N>(i, f) is basically a switch (i) over all values from 0 to N - 1.
